# Continous function transform equals zero, then function equals zero in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: integration, continuity, laplace-transform, transformation

Im proving the following statement:

Let $\alpha>0$, the gaussian weight $\omega(z)= \frac{\alpha}{\pi}e^{-\alpha \left | z \right |^2}$ is the unique continuous, radial weight verifying $\int_\mathbb{C} \omega(z) dA(z)=1$ such that for polynomials p and q under the inner product
$$
\left \langle p,q \right \rangle = \int_\mathbb{C} p(z)\overline{q(z)}\omega(z) dA(z)
$$
the operations of multiplication for $\alpha z$ and differentiation are adjoint.

I supposed $\omega$ a weight verifying the conditions and got to te final equality, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{ 0 \}$
$$
\int_0^\infty r^{2n + 1} \omega (r) dr = \frac{\alpha}{\pi}\int_0^\infty r^{2n + 1} e^{-\alpha r^2} dr
$$
I need to prove the following property in order to end the proof.
Let $f : [0,+ \infty ) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function that verifies $\forall n\in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0 \}$ the following equality:
$$
\int_0^\infty r^{2n + 1} f (r) dr = 0
$$
Prove that $f$ is the zero function.

Comment: f is not a non negative function

Comment: Why the downvotes? I think this question is alright.

Comment: Can you explain what $\mathrm{d}A(z)$ is? Is it the typical area element in $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathrm dz \mathrm d\overline{z}$ ?

Comment: where z = x + iy, dA(z) = dxdy